# Slow files transfers between pidgin/empathy and msn/wlm

Tags: empathy, pidgin, msn

I always get low transfer rate by sending or receiving files to msn/wlm. What can I do to solve that?
Tks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check in the advanced msn account settings in pidgin, whether the "Allow direct connections" option is enabled. Also make sure that both parties have the latest version of the respective programs installed.

Comment: It worked fine on WLM protocol at the first try, but just on first. Then it start to fail on send files. About the transfer rate, it is low on emesene and amsn too. And I'm trying to send/receive files to/from WLM users on Windows.